# CSS input type="file" hidden but only for 1 class?

Tags: css, nuget, blazor

I have a weird issue with a Nuget package of mine where the Blazor [Parameter] works as a project reference to not display the standard button with ShowCustomButton = true or false.

Later today I will setup a custom feed to Debug the Nuget package, as it may be related to the linked styled sheet:

```
<link href="~/_content/DataJuggler.Blazor.FileUpload/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I am already using this CSS to make the standard input file button turn into a pointer when the mouse is over the button.

```
input[type=file], /* FF, IE7+, chrome (except button) */
input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button 
{ 
    /* chrome and blink button */
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I can easily solve the Nuget issue in a project that consumes it by adding the display: none;

```
input[type=file], /* FF, IE7+, chrome (except button) */
input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button 
{ 
    /* chrome and blink button */
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
```

The problem is my sample page has two file upload samples, one with a Standard Button, and one with a Custom button. If I implement the solution above, the Standard Button stops showing (as intended).

I realize outside of my sample project, most developers are either going to show a custom button or not, not a mix of both in the same project, but for knowledge sake I would like to be able to do something like:

```
.customfileupload
{
    input[type=file]
    { 
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Visual Studio doesn't like the above format, so I am sure it isn't valid CSS.

As the title states, is there a way to select input[type=file] but only for 1 class?

In case I am not explaining this correctly and anyone is bored and wants to help out an open source project, the code and sample is here:

https://github.com/DataJuggler/BlazorFileUpload

To duplicate the issue, run the sample project first and you will see both buttons:

[image]

Next remove the BlazorInputFile and BlazorFileUpload projects, and add the Nuget package DataJuggler.Core.FileUpload to the Sample project.

Run the project again, and you see:

[image]

It is just confusing because Nuget usually works the same as a project reference.

Thanks. I am having one of those computers do what you tell them, not what you want days.

Comment: the correct css would be .customfileupload  input[type=file] {  display: none;}

Comment: Thank you Alvaro, I will try it. I will update as soon as I get a break from work.

Answer (score 0):

File input requires different CSS styling then a buttons. 
Maybe [this helps](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) or [this](https://benmarshall.me/styling-file-inputs/).

Answer (score 0):

Alvaro Menéndez gets the credit, and I am just posting his answer in this section.

Because my input file also contains a custom button and a Status message, I had to do add the class where it is visible, and the second class applies the hidden only to the input file.

I will write this down as 'What I learned today.'

Thank you Alvaro!

```
.customupload
{
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
}
.customupload input[type=file]
{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```